# what is the best approach to show that F is complex differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification

Suppose that f is differentiable on an open set G and $z_0 ∈ G$.

Let

$F(z) = \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0},$ $(z \neq z_0), F(z_0) = f
′
(z_0)$

Prove that F is differentiable on G.

I wanted to use an argument which relied on the definition of differentiability to show that $F'(z)=lim_{h \to 0}\frac{F(z+h)-F(z)}{h}$. But apparently you can't use arguments like that here , because then it would imply that it is true for the reals also. Now I'm thinking that if f is differentiable it has a taylor series so if I can show that F(z) has a taylor series then this will imply that F is differentiable.

Is this the right approach ? and if not is- there any suggestions as to what approach\proofs might prove more fruitful ?

Comment: Well,  $F$ is clearly differentiable at every $z\ne z_0$.

Comment: Yes, if you knew that $f$ has a Taylor series expansion around $z_0$ then yes, you can show that $F(z)$ also has a Taylor expansion at $z_0$. One simply divides the exansion of $f-f(z_0)$ by $z-z_0$. However, Cauchy needed this result to prove the Cauchy formula. So, just be aware that there are other proofs that only use the definition of complex differentiable, but are more subtle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close with the Taylor series argument. Here are the details.

For the point $z_0$, it is $z_0\in G$ therefore there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $D(z_0,\varepsilon)\subset G$. One can write $f$ as a power series in this disc, centered at $z_0$: it is $f(z)=f(z_0)+f'(z_0)(z-z_0)+\frac{f''(z_0)}{2!}(z-z_0)^2+\dots$ Therefore $f(z)-f(z_0)=f'(z_0)(z-z_0)+\frac{f''(z_0)}{2!}(z-z_0)^2+\dots$ Now we can write $f(z)-f(z_0)=g(z)(z-z_0)$, with $g(z)=\displaystyle{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(k+1)}(z_0)}{(k+1)!}(z-z_0)^k}$ and $g(z_0)=f'(z_0)$. It is for $z\neq z_0$, $g(z)=\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$. Since $g$ is being represented by a power series on the disc $D(z_0,\varepsilon)$, it is holomorphic there. Now for $z\in G\setminus D(z_0,\varepsilon)$, it is obvious that $F$ is holomorphic on every such $z$, since it is a product of holomorphic functions $(z\mapsto f(z)-f(z_0, z\mapsto\frac{1}{z-z_0})$. By all above, $F$ is holomorphic on its domain.